# How to create Tgrid at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I am new to Delphi creating runtime Tgrid and want to add some rows and columns. I googled but not getting any thing. i am at level zero. what i have tried i mentioned it below.This code is showing nothing on my form.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Grid : TGrid;
begin
  Grid := TGrid.Create(Form1);
  Grid.Visible := True;
  Grid.Margins.Left := 10;
  Grid.Margins.Right := 10;
  Grid.Margins.Top := 10;
  Grid.Margins.Bottom := 10;
  Grid.RowCount := 5;
end;
```

Comment: This Q is essentially a sub-Q of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005373/creating-components-at-runtime-delphi.

Comment: What's stopping you simply placing the Grid on the form at design-time with its Visible property set to False and at run-time simply set its Visible to true when you want it to be?

Comment: Please do not edit your question once you have already received answers. Specificly do not destroy edits that others have done, unless you are very sure, that you need to do so. I rolled back to the previous version.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Ok

Answer (score 1):

The grid control must have a parent control. Indeed, naturally, the system must know *where* (on the screen) to put your control!

You probably want the grid to have the form as its parent. If so, just add `Grid.Parent := Form1;` after the construction of the grid.

Of course, when you add this missing line of code and get to see the grid, you'll very soon notice that your `Margins` assignments have no effect. That's because by default you control the position of the control (no pun intended) manually using its `Top`, `Left`, `Height`, and `Width` properties.

But should you start experimenting with the `Align` property, you'll discover the effect of the margins, if you also set `AlignWithMargins` to `True`. For instance, if you set `Align` to `alClient`, the control will occupy all of its parent's client area, save the margins.

Comment: + There is no benefits from setting `TMargins` without using `TAlign`

Comment: @Sami is quite right. The margins will only have any effect if you also set the `Align` property to something other than `alNone`, and also set `AlignWithMargins` to `True`.

Comment: You can always edit the answer to include more helpful stuff @Andreas Rejbrand :)

Comment: Thanks all for your reply it really helped me.

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Grid : TGrid;
begin
  Grid := TGrid.Create(Form1);
  Grid.Visible := True;
  Grid.Parent := ListBox1;
  Grid.Align := Grid.Align.alClient;
end;

now its working but how to add columns ?

if you find any proper example online please let me know that shows proper workout on it.

Comment: Having a listbox control as parent is unusual, especially when you use `alClient` (the RHS can be `alClient` alone), because then the entire list box will be hidden!

Comment: @DharmeshBhagatwala To create a column, write `TColumn.Create(Grid).Parent := Grid;`. The column is created with `Grid` as owner and parent. Access a column´s properties with `Grid.Columns[i]` where `i` is the 0-based index.